How to Populate MS word on power automate with Image's ORIGINAL size (Dimension)
I try to Populate MS word with Picture (Picture content control in developer tool on MS word) but size is depend on Picture content control and I need to manual select "reset" original size in MS word
.
So Anyone know, how to use Power automate populate the Picture with ORIGINAL size (Dimension).
Power Automate / FLOW
MS WORD
Please share any idea to me . Thank you and have a good day !!
